# Spring boot stateless security with redis cache data

Tags: spring, security, spring-boot, redis, stateless

While doing some practice examples to learn spring security, I come up with some following use case. But I did not find best possible approach using spring security. Could some one please help me on this

I have angularJs application, Spring boot application running on different servers . In redis cache I have user info(role, and some other info) with gsid as key. In each rest call I am passing gsid as cookie. Now I want to validate each request in the Spring security Filter by fetching user info from the redis cache before sending to @Restcontroller.

what could be best approach to authenticate and authorize the request using spring boot security.

Comment: Google on spring security sample applications you will get many but with redis may not find much.

Answer (score 1):

Use [spring-session with redis](http://docs.spring.io/spring-session/docs/current/reference/html5/#httpsession-redis), it also provides integration with spring-security.